# Do mindless creatures get feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Do creatures that have **no** Intelligence Score ("Int —" in the stat block) gain Feats? I'm creating some monsters but I failed to find the answer for this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Mindless creatures have only bonus feats and no skill ranks

Creatures that have Intelligence as a nonability are called *mindless*, which also gives such creatures immunity to mind-affecting effects. [Oozes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Ooze), [constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct), and [vermin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Vermin) are the most common mindless creatures, but many [plants](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Plant) and [undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead) are also noted as sometimes being without an Intelligence score, therefore mindless. Undoubtedly, there are outliers and exceptions; this is *Pathfinder*, after all.

Being mindless doesn't prevent a creature from having *bonus* feats, usually gained from just being what it is. (That is, not, like, fighter bonus feats but bonus feats for just being, like, a giant scorpion or whatever.) For example, a creature to which the template [skeleton](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/skeleton) has been applied gains as a bonus feat Improved Initiative even though the skeleton template renders the creature mindless.

Comment: @GMJoe  Each of the types I linked to explains what mindless means, individually noting that mindless creatures of that type don't get feats and skills. Over on the [Monster Creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-creation) page, it's a little clearer but still just a footnote instead of clear, absolute rule. I figured the querent would follow the link to the type of creature he's making and get detailed results from that. If you've a suggestion for greater clarity, I'm happy to oblige or have this answer edited.